# Merge tags from remote repository and keep tag history?

Tags: git, tags, git-merge

I'm trying to merge kernel revision tags into a kernel for an android device using git.

So far I've done this

```
git fetch <linux-stable reop> <branch>

git fetch <linux-stable reop> <branch>
```

To merge a tag, I ran `git merge <tag>` such as `git merge v3.10.45`

This makes all the necessary changes in the code. The problem with this, is that it does not show to commit history of the commits that it applied to reach the tag. It applied say 10 commits to reach a tag but in the log it showsit as "`Merge tag <tag>`" with myself as the author (when I didn't author the commits from linux-stable).

How would I merge a tag and keep the commits that made up that tag? Is there anyway to pick all the commits between tags?

Thanks.

Comment: It's not completely clear to me what you're expecting, but git doesn't work whatever way it is that you are expecting.  One thing in particular is that a tag is simply a human-readable name for a specific SHA-1 (and, if "annotated" tag, whatever additional info the tagger put in, but again it ultimately resolves to a specific SHA-1.  That's one single commit, not a set of commits.  To get a *set* of commits you must refer instead to the commit graph, which is formed from the commits themselves, independent of tags or other names.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not author those 10 commits but you did author the result of merging those commits into whatever branch you're merging into.

To see the commits that are part of the merge commit, you can look at the history, e.g., with `git log --graph --oneline`. There you can see all branches that go into the merge commit.